# Wildfly & log4j

Tags: log4j, wildfly-10

The property has standalone.xml

```
<System-properties>
<Property name = "eclipselink.archive.factory" value = "org.jipijapa.eclipselink.JBossArchiveFactoryImpl" />
<Property name = "-Dlog4j.configuration" value = "file:///d:Work/Options/log4j.xml" />
</ System-properties>
```

But in the logs is a warning

```
log4j: WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j: WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j: WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Connected to server
```

What I did not = (

I have my own log4j1.12.17 in modules

Comment: What do you mean by you have your own log4j module?

Comment: It seems that you don't correctly set the path ///d:Work/Options/log4j.xml. Have you already checked it?